# Correct way to masquerade IP in iptables

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I have an ubuntu 14.04 machine running  with multiple NICs. One of them have external internet access. I would like to enable external network access for all the other LAN interfaces. What is the correct way of masquerading in iptables assuming eth0 is the WAN interface. I have tried :

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -j MASQUERADE`

which is working fine, but most of the sites explain it with'

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

What is the difference and which is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use the second one since you have multiple NICs.

Only the packages that go out of the interface connected to the Internet have to be masqueraded.

`-o` means outgoing Interface so it's only a further reduction of the general first option

For more information and getting started with iptables have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.google.de/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/177621/the-beginners-guide-to-iptables-the-linux-firewall/amp/)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. The first one wont detect main interface?

Comment: The first one tells iptables to masqueraded any outgoing package also on the internal NIC. This works ... but is not needed and might even slow down the network

Comment: I will use the 2nd one